# How to block TFS Check In with a Note/Reminder

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

To debug code you sometimes find yourself doing a hack in the code. The problem is that you have to remind yourself to remove the hack before you check in the code.

Is there any mechanism in VS to remind you to remove the hack. I mean something you can set in VS to block the check in with a custom message/note reminding yourself why  the check-in was blocked ?

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

- Use conditional compilation so that the "hack" can be turned on/off depending on what compilation platform you use, then just make sure you build and release an appropriate platform with the hack disabled
- Write a unit test that will fail while the hack is in place, then configure a gated check-in with tests set to constitute a build failure.
- Write a custom check-in policy, although this is going to be a huge pain and I don't recommend it.

Comment: My personal opinion is that the unit test approach is the best one.